# Equivalent to sp_executesql in Sybase

Tags: sybase

What's the equivalent to sp_executesql of Sql Server in sybase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `exec()` is what you're looking for.  See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands56.htm.

Answer (score 1):

@jasir: the limitation to 255 characters results from your procedure definition. Isn't possible to extend this limit by defining e.g. varchar(1024)?

ASE Refrence Manual 15.7 (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X30305.htm) 
states for command execute:

> string is a literal string containing part of a Transact-SQL command
>   to execute. There **are no restrictions** to the number of characters
>   supplied with the literal string.

However, sometimes a system on top of sybase (e.g. Kondor+, a product for financial markets uses ASE 15.x as DB) may set limits. In this Kondor+ it is not possible to use

```
exec( @SQLQuery)
```

in its so called OpenReport (a stored procedure), if the variable @SQLQuery exceeds 256 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For older ASE, you can use this workaround:

There is stored procedure [sp_remotesql](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs184.htm).
You can use it to run query on local server too, you just have to local server to servers:

`sp_addserver local, NULL, <servername>`

Where `<servername>` is name of local server (from sql.ini).

You can add shortcut procedure for running sql:

```
create procedure sp_exec_dynsql @p_cmd varchar(255)
as
begin
   exec sp_remotesql "local", @p_cmd
end
```

Unfortunatelly, you are limited to 255 characters in your sql.